# Install OS Before Adding Hard Drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

My current setup is an SSD with Windows installed on it and an HDD for data. I bought a second SSD and second HDD. I want to install Ubuntu Server on the second SSD and let it use the second HDD for data. Should I format these hard drives in Windows before I install Ubuntu? Or, should I hook up the hard drives then start the computer up with the Live CD before I let Windows detect the hard drives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or, should I hook up the hard drives then start the computer up with
>   the Live CD before I let Windows detect the hard drives?

**Yes.** And you should choose manual partitioning in the installer, and tell it to create your `/home` and `swap` partitions on the HDD, and your root`/` partition on the SSD.

---

Also, I recommend you disconnect your other HDD and SSD during the install

Comment: If I disconnect the other two hard drives, will that affect my ability to set up a dual boot that asks which OS I want to boot to each time I startup?

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Well 1st things first are you using UEFI or MBR booting?

Comment: I am building this computer as a learning process. So, I don't quite understand your question, even after some googling. When I prepared the USB for Ubuntu, I used UEFI. It seems that MBR can't handle large hard drives? My HDDs are both 4 TB.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 I guess you can leave the other drives connected, but be sure to choose "something else" in the installer and tell it to install the bootloader to the SSD with Windows